# Dynamically refresh jquery datatable using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Is there a way I can automatically refresh data in a jquery datatable? I want to click a button that will make an AJAX request to return new data and insert the data in the datatable. I want something like:

```
$("#update_button").click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: productType,
        url: "/api/getproducts",
        success: function(data, status) {
            $('#products_table').DataTable( {
                data: data,
                columns: [
                    { title: "col 1" },
                    { title: "col 2" },
                    { title: "col 3" },
                    { title: "col 4" },
                    { title: "col 5" },
                    { title: "col 6" }
                ]
            });
        },
        error: function(data, status, res) {
            console.log('error...');
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
});
```

However this gives me 'table cannot be re-initialized' error... Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: See `https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()` , `ajax.reload()` is an available library to reload jquery datatables from their ajax source.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049439/how-to-set-dynamically-the-ajax-url-of-a-datatable/32049573#32049573

Comment: You should to take the initialisation code out of the click event and simply call `draw()` to refresh the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#myName").on("change", function(){
   tbl.ajax.url("<?php  echo RP_SSP ?>server_processing_reservTables.php?myName="+$(this).val()).load();
 });
```